# bootstrap not picking up margin between divs

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

so i have basically this set up:

```
__________________________      ______________
|                         |    |              |
|                         |    |   card div   |
|     this is a chart     |    ----------------   this margin between the two divs 
|                         |    ----------------   is not being picked up by 
|       in a div          |    |   card div   |
|                         |    |              |
---------------------------    ----------------
```

so basically as you can see i have a chart which is line chart and i created a div similar to a card with rounded corners and i'm using bootstrap to style them just like this. the problem is the two card div does not have margin between the two of them they are attached together without the margin and i don't know why.

what i did:

```
const measurment = [
        { title: "Last Body Weight", value: "154",unit:"lb",subValue:"13% Fat",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
        { title: "Last Body Fat", value: "98",unit:"%",subValue:"85 BPM",date:"05/14/2020 04:12"},
    ]

<div>
      <Row>
            
            <Col lg="9">
      <ActualLineChart data={bodyWeightAndFatData}/>
      </Col>   
      <Col lg="3" md="3" sm="3" xs="3">                  
                  {measurment.map(measurment => {
                            return (
                                <Card
                                  style={measurment.style}
                                  title={measurment.title}
                                  value={measurment.value}
                                  unit = {measurment.unit}
                                  subValue={measurment.subValue}
                                  date={measurment.date}
                                />
                            )
                          })
                        }
      
      </Col>
      </Row>
      
      <Row className="mt-4">
          <Col>
            <ActualScatterLine data={bodyWeightAndFatData}/>
          </Col>
      </Row>      
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap column does not **vertically** regulate the distance between two elements. To adjust the spacing between elements **vertically**, you can manually handle them using `flex` and `justify-content`.

**Example using `flex` and `justify-content`:**

```css
:root {
  --height: 200px;
  --padding: 15px;
}

.standard-box {
  height: calc(var(--height) + var(--padding));
}

.container-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.small-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(var(--height) * .5);
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 standard-box box-1"></div>
    <div class="col-6 container-box">
      <div class="small-box box-2"></div>
      <div class="small-box box-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This method is not recommended if you need a dynamic number of boxes. Better to use the [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) display to arrange elements in 2 dimensions (vertical & horizontal).